# NSFaceIDUsageDescription is there for Face ID Usage Description. How about touch ID Usage Description?

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist

I wanted to understand that Why don't have any key for Touch ID Usage Description.

However, we need to specify key NSFaceIDUsageDescription (aka Privacy - Face ID Usage Description) in app's Info.plist. This is because we are using a Privacy feature from iOS. Similarly in case of Touch Id also we are using a Privacy feature of iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple documentation says this:

In any project that uses biometrics, include the NSFaceIDUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file. Without this key, the system won’t allow your app to use Face ID. The value for this key is a string that the system presents to the user the first time your app attempts to use Face ID. The string should clearly explain why your app needs access to this authentication mechanism. 
**The system doesn’t require a comparable usage description for Touch ID.**